# RewriteRule acces to the main folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to make a rewrite rule to redirect to what the user has typed right after the main url, so no folder (like www.site.com/user1), I think that would mean to access $0 which doesn't work...

The rule I'm trying to use is:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+) show-user.php?user=$0
```

But it does not work...

Any ideas?

---

Ok, new file and it's still wrong...

Full .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+) test.php?var1=$1 [L]
```

full test.php file:

```
<?php
    print_r($_GET);
?>
```

Ouput for domain/user1

```
Array ( [var1] => test )
```

It makes no sense :(

How can I make sure in php var1 will be user1 (as it should be) in the example above? I think the rewrite rule is wrong somehow...

Comment: fine, no ', just 0-9a-zA-Z then :)

Comment: yes, it is eanbled... but in php the value retrieved for either $1 or $0 in .htaccess is "show", not "user1" as it should be...

Answer (score 3):

The parameters are not 0-indexed

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+) show-user.php?user=$1
```

Comment: Nice pair of eyes, can I borrow?

Comment: What is the URL you're trying to access?

Comment: In your PHP, `$_GET['user']` will equal whatever was passed in to the file after the domain. So for example: domain.com/show will go to `show-user.php?user=show`.

Comment: the problem is that if I type in the browser domain/user1 , the variable $_GET['user'] = "show", which makes no sense...

Comment: You must be overwriting it somewhere. What does `print_r($_GET)` output?

Comment: it somehow reads the first part of "show-user.php" I think, I have no idea why

Comment: Try and change the filename. What happens?

Comment: I figured it out. And btw, I was right, the problem was indeed the RewriteRule . Here is the solution: RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ test.php?var1=$1 [L] - so I had to put $ to mark the end of the string